# FullCalendar .start don't get properly hour

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

This problem is sending me crazy. I do not know what to do to solve it sincerely. My calendar shows this display:

[image]

and it is initialized in the following way:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        'defaultView': 'multiColAgendaDay',
        'height': BackendCalendar.getCalendarHeight(),
        'editable': true,
        'firstDay': 1,          //Lunedì
        'slotMinutes': 30,
        'snapMinutes': 15,
        'axisFormat': 'H:mm',
        'timeFormat': 'H(:mm)',
        'allDayText': EALang['all_day'], 
        ...
```

I get the date of start in the following way:

```
console.log($calendar.fullCalendar('getView').start);
```

but instead of returning this (as was the case with version 1.6.1)

> Fri Oct 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)

Is returned this:

> Fri Oct 23 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)

This broke my whole code!!
Ideas?

**MY TIMEZONE**

I'm in Italy / Rome

**FULL CALENDAR VERSION**

2.3.1

Comment: Can you post a fiddle that replicates your issue ?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/JackIlpazzo/jc07k3dd/ but it doesn't working properly without a server. Try it with bitnami or something like

Comment: Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc07k3dd/1/). However, comparing the javascript code with the snippet you've provided it doesn't seem to be the same (missing firstDat, soltMinutes, ....). I'm afraid that if you can't replicate the issue in a fiddle I'm not going to be able to help you.

Comment: Seems a timezone problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to use your local time, you need to set *timezone: local* in your fullcalendar options object, because fullcalendar is not ignoring timezone anymore.

If you want it to use given timezone (Italy/Rome) you may want to check moment-timezone as well as moment-timezone-data for it to work (moment.js is the main dependency).

Please, check the timezone docs here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Since you are moving from 1.x to 2.x maybe you want to check this "changelog": http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/

Comment: What do you mean with timezone: local? Could you please provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: @Dillinger You should check the documentation for timezone here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

There is an explanation for every value, in this case for "local" it is:

"local" (the client's timezone)

Use this mode if you store timezone information for your events and you want events displayed differently depending on the local timezone of each end-user's computer.